# Accessibility Services getBoundsInScreen - how to query

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I want to get the `rect` boundaries for a view (which is `node.getBoundsInScreen`). It shows up in the debugger but I can't seem to find a way to access it through code.

[image]

Querying it through code requires you to pass a `new Rect()`. How can I get the values here?

[image]

Comment: just pass a `Rect` object, like: `Rect out = new Rect(); node.getBoundsInScreen(out); Log.d(TAG, "out: " + out);`

Comment: @pskink I had a question regarding the XML dump. When I run the dump with uiautomator I get the resource-id for a view, but the AccessibilityNodeInfo does not have it